# How to keep radio buttons on same line in form

Tags: html, forms, css

I have a form with input boxes and radio buttons. If I have long text in a `<td>` which jumps to the next line, somehow this affects the second radio button so that the label and the radio button become stacked. 
See the live code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/leopardy/bLnLwoht/

Things I've tried:
-If I remove the long text, for example delete the word 'Intercontinental', this fixes my problem but I need that long word.
-If I change the width of the form area to something bigger such as 500px this also fixes my problem but I need the width of the form to be 450px and the width of the input boxes to be 200px.

Also, I would like to be able to keep it all on the same line and not have to put my radio buttons on separate lines. Ideally, I would like to have the word 'Enabled' be aligned with the input box above it followed by the radio button, followed by the word Disabled, followed by the radio button and all this without passing the right side boundaries of the input button.  Is there a way to do this?

I will add the code here as well:

CSS

```
.form_area {
    height: auto;
    width : 450px;
}
.inputs_table  input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;       
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form_area">
<form id="create_form">
<div>
    <table class="inputs_table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input name="name" id="name_input" type="text" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Intercontinental Location:</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="location_input" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Feature:</td>
                <td>
                    <label for="one">Enabled</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="input_enabled" name="feature" value="true">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="two">Disabled</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="input_disabled" name="feature" value="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div></form></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple fix here, **put both the radio buttons and labels in the same `td`**.

So change:

```
<td>
    <label for="one">Enabled</label>
    <input type="radio" id="input_enabled" name="feature" value="true">
</td>
<td>
    <label for="two">Disabled</label>
    <input type="radio" id="input_disabled" name="feature" value="false" />
</td>
```

to:

```
<td>
    <label for="one">Enabled</label>
    <input type="radio" id="input_enabled" name="feature" value="true">
    <label for="two">Disabled</label>
    <input type="radio" id="input_disabled" name="feature" value="false" />
</td>
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLnLwoht/1/)

Comment: {facepalm} I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks!